# How do I set up a div under the header which fills up the remaining space?

Tags: css, html

prnt.sc/ha3dag

The black div is the header, which is 40 pixels high. The blue div under it needs to fill up the remaining space without going over the screen height and causing an overflow-y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving us a lot to go on. When you post a question in the future, make sure you add a little code to give us a better idea of the issue. That being said, I think I can assist.

You have something like this:

```
<div style="height:40px">
<h1>SomeContentHere</h1>
</div>
<div>
<h1>OtherContent</h1>
</div>
```

but instead of setting a hard coded value, I like to do percentages.

```
<div style="height:10%">
<h1>SomeContentHere</h1>
</div>
<div style="height:90%">
<h1>OtherContent</h1>
</div>
```

This should change based on available screen size since it is a percentage and not a static value.

If you have a static value for your header, you could do something like this:

```
  <div style="height:40px">
    <h1>SomeContentHere</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="height: calc(100% - 40px)">
    <h1>OtherContent</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to do the header in percentages. It's a header. I need the header hardcoded.

Comment: height: calc(100% - (40px)   - try that

Comment: Let me know if you need additional assistance.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Don't forget to mark the answer. Good luck.